# Join Dom Elements with a Character in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of anchor tags that I want to have comma separated.

```
<!-- Current -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="some_url1" class="link">Something 1</a>
    <a href="some_url2" class="link">Something 2</a>
    <a href="some_url3" class="link">Something 3</a>
    <a href="some_url4" class="link">Something 4</a>
</div>

<!-- Result After JQuery Function -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="some_url1" class="link">Something 1</a>,
    <a href="some_url2" class="link">Something 2</a>,
    <a href="some_url3" class="link">Something 3</a>,
    <a href="some_url4" class="link">Something 4</a>,
</div>
```

EDIT:
How would I do this using jquery?

Comment: Are you sure you want the comma after the last anchor?

Comment: @Robusto, It was really depending on how i wanted to implement the list.  It's a dynamically growing list.  And I already have a way to remove commas.  So just removing and re-adding all commas' before adding the list was one possible solution(not what i went with)

Comment: @Diodeus: Yeah, seems rather harsh. Perhaps someone being a bit downvote-happy because Logan didn't phrase his question in the form of a question? (Logan: Always best to actually ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yeah, but plenty of vastly less clear questions on this site escape with no down-vote. Besides, the question is implicit if the title and text are taken together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#wrapper > a:not(:last-child)').after(',');
```

Comment: sorry - i thought i did this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#wrapper > a:not(:last-child)').after(',');
```

if you don't want the comma after the last one...

Alternatively you could use CSS generated content

```
#wrapper a:after
{
  content: ',';
}
```

Comment: The CSS solution still won't work for a huge number of users, although things are improving... And of course, it would have the comma after the last anchor, which I suspect the OP doesn't really want although he did show one...

Comment: Archaic requirements prevent that from being a solution =(

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wrapper a').after(',');
```